# ngRepeat order fail with accent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of strings with some accent. But the `orderBy` filter doesn't seem to work correctly with them, as you can see [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcKg6/9/).

How can I improve the sort? Do I need to add an option in `orderBy`?

Comment: For your information, I've edited my answer. Give it a try :) !

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two strings with the [`String.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method. It's then easy to create your own filter to sort your array:

```
MyApp.filter('myOrderBy', function () {
    return function (array, property, reverse) {
        var result = array.sort(function (object1, object2) {
            if (angular.isUndefined(property)) {
                return object1.localeCompare(object2);
            }

            return object1[property].localeCompare(object2[property]);
        });

        return reverse ? result.reverse() : result;
    };
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/23at9phb/)</kbd>

Comment: There's a function which is used inside this filter that isn't defined: `objectToArray()`.

Comment: @MateusDuartePoncedeLeon I've edited my answer to suggest a far better alternative. Have a look :) !

Comment: The problem with that is the narrow browser options that can deal with this new method on Javascript. Indeed: way better in terms of readability, performance, but we don't have a proper way to deal with some legacy browsers.

Comment: @MateusDuartePoncedeLeon In this basic form, without additional parameters, `String.localeCompare()` is really old and largely supported, even by obsolete browsers.